# Which bank was the oldest surviving bank in the world prior to MPS getting that status?

Tags: 15th-century, banking, business-history

> [Banca Monte dei Paschi di Siena S.p.A.](http://english.mps.it) [...] (MPS) is the oldest surviving bank in the world [...]

<sup>*Wikipedia*: [1](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Monte_dei_Paschi_di_Siena) (and [2](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_oldest_banks), [3](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/History_of_banking))</sup>

Assuming that this is correct, and using the same criteria, which was the latest bank to lose that status? And when did that happen?

Comment: Finding the bank with the earliest date of founding that is still in operation is a fairly easy task. Finding the next older bank, which has closed it's doors, is not so easy, and most likely beyond the research interests of anyone frequenting this site. How far back do we go for the closing dates? If someone found a 'bank' that was only open a year, but was founded in 2BC, would that 'win'? How _could_ it win, after all, since there _might_ be an even older one somewhere?

Comment: VtC as Too Broad, because of my comment above. Before someone complains, I fully realize there can really only be one answer, therefor it's perhaps by definition not too broad. The trouble is, the rules of engagement themselves are too broad and need to be more narrowly defined. Otherwise, the First National Bank of Ugh wins, since it was opened in 14000BC, with a required deposit of three antlers and a free spear given.... it didn't close its doors until 9023BC, when Bronk was accused of fiduciary nincompoopery.  - "I win"

Comment: @CGCampbell I don't think that's what the question is asking. As I read it, it's asking which bank held that title at the *exact point in time* that MPS got the title. So any bank that closed before MPS opened would be immediately out of the running.

Answer (score 1):

That's probably [Banco di San Giorgio](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bank_of_Saint_George) founded in 1407, and closed in 1805.

Comment: What do you mean with "probably"?

Comment: @GlenTheUdderboat I don't understand that question.

Comment: @LennartRegebro I guess he's implying that "probably" isn't satisfactory, and wants something more.